# Is there a way to set .gitignore so that a file is ignored except while clone?

Tags: git

As stated in the title, is there a way to set .gitignore file so that a file is ignored except when being clone?

I am now working on a project that will be tested on 5 machines and all will be updated regularly. Using git pull makes things simple, except when I need to change the configuration files. For some reason I need to change the configuration file frequently when I am working on localhost during development but they can be remain the same for other machines. Currently I simply ignore the configuration files, but then I need to copy the configuration files after cloning the code to a new machine. So, to make things even simpler, is there a way I can set .gitignore file so that a file is ignored except when git clone?

Answer (score 0):

Git maintains a file which contain rules according to which files are ignored.

You can mention your rules in this file

```
.git/info/exclude
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could have some generic config file in your repo (which would clone along with repo) and then put it in .gitignore so it wouldn't be noticed as change and untrack it so there wouldn't be problems with pull.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use .gitignore for this, you might want to change the default config.
When you do not want to use Maven with an assembly and test dir's, try to make a config script.
On Unix this would be something like

```
target=$1
case ${target} in
  "site1") sed -i 's/^host=.*/host=site1/' xx.cfg ;; // sed -i only on Linux
  *) echo ${target} not supported
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, on the machine where you change the config files, run the following: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`. This will make it so when you run `git commit -a`, the specified file will not be added to the index, and thus not committed, even though it was changed. Then you do not have to worry about ignoring the file on the 5 other machines.