# Ignore a tracked file for changes

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a local file that must be ignored for changes.  But I also have a template of it in the repo, to guide the user creating it.

I added it to `.gitignore` to not have it polluting `git status`, but it still does.

Is it possible to have it ignored for changes, but at the same time making sure it IS in the repo, and retrieved on a `git clone`?

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461882/git-how-to-automatically-ignore-a-file-after-a-clone, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313564/is-there-a-way-to-set-gitignore-so-that-a-file-is-ignored-except-while-clone, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794931/keep-file-in-a-git-repo-but-dont-track-changes

Comment: I first tracked it, then added it to .gitignore.  But what I wanted is `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. Sorry, I did search but couldn't find an answer.  Thank you for the response!